# Reading Custom Headers on Lambda Edge request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am using a Lambda Edge triggered by viewer-request to control access to a Cloudfront Distribution Origin (S3 Bucket). I want to allow/deny access to the distribution by sending an IdToken and a UID (user ID) string.
My code basically decodes the IdToken and reads a decodedUID inside it, then compares it to the UID passed as a header and if they match or not it allows/deny access to the Origin

I am using SAM to deploy all of this, when I test this code locally it works as it should but when I deploy the changes to AWS one of the two headers is not being received by the lambda

I am sending two headers with each request to the Cloudfront Distribution

- Authorization
- UID

But the UID Header is never reaching the lambda edge in the event

I am using Nodejs14.x as runtime, when I run `console.log(request.headers)` I see the Authorization header with the token but not the UID

Does someone know why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I managed to send the UID value as a query parameter but that solution is not fitting to what I need

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I also faced similar issue. I set a customer header with CloudFront Function for `viewer-request` and tried to read it from Lambda@Edge in `origin-request` but some header has been missing.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up passing the second header value as a query parameter since it was not crucial or sensitive data

Comment: I solved the problem. Any headers that need to pass to origin **MUST** specify in origin request policy that is using by the CloudFront distribution. Otherwise it is going to be dropped by CloudFront.

Comment: Can you share an example and add it as a response?

Comment: I'm not sure if it work on your case due to it is a different event. For my case I did not read a custom headers in `viewer-request`.

Comment: Wait. I think I found your problem. Try `X-UID` instead due to any non-standard HTTP headers must use `X-Name` form.